# coreplot - only part of the graph responds to user interaction

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have implemented a graph with scatterplot in landscape mode. I have enabled user interaction on the plotspace. The graph view only seems to recognize user interactions on the left half of the graph and not on the right. I have made sure that there are no views overlapping with the graph view and it is on the top of the view stack. Can anyone suggest what may be wrong ?? .. Thanks

The code is here:

Initialisation of graph host:

```
-(void)initgraphhost{
    CGRect graphcontainer=CGRectMake(0,0,568,300);
    self.graphhostview = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:graphcontainer];
    self.graphhostview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.graphhostview.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.graphhostview];
}
```

Adding graphs :

```
-(void)AddGraph:(NSString *)graphname tographcontainer:(CPTGraphHostingView *)host{
    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:host.bounds];
    graph.borderColor=(__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor clearColor]);
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:nil]];
    host.hostedGraph = graph;
    //  plotspace= (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    CPTXYGraph *currentgraph=(CPTXYGraph *)host.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *currentplotspace=(CPTXYPlotSpace *) host.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    currentgraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom=25;
    currentgraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft=45;
    currentgraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop=10;
    [currentgraph setBackgroundColor:[gBkGcolor CGColor]];
    currentplotspace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)currentgraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    currentplotspace.delegate=self;
    currentplotspace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;
    //Configure layer hierarchy
    NSArray *chartLayers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLabels],[NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMajorGridLines],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypePlots],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeMinorGridLines],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisLines],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisTitles],

                        nil];
    currentgraph.topDownLayerOrder = chartLayers;

    //Styles and formats

    CPTMutableLineStyle  *clearlineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    clearlineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    clearlineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle  *gridLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    gridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor darkGrayColor];
    gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5f;

    NSArray *dashpatternArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2], nil];
    gridLineStyle.dashPattern=dashpatternArray;

    CPTMutableLineStyle  *AxisLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    AxisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    AxisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle  *TickLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    TickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
    TickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *textstyle=[CPTTextStyle textStyle];
    textstyle.fontSize=12;
    textstyle.color=[CPTColor blackColor];

    CPTMutableTextStyle *ylabelstyle=[CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    ylabelstyle.fontSize=12;
    ylabelstyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];

    NSNumberFormatter *Yformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [Yformatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
    [Yformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

    NSDate *refDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
    CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:CurrentDF];
    timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;

    //Format axes

    //X axis
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)currentgraph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength =CPTDecimalFromFloat(CurrentXinterval);
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = TickLineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = clearlineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = AxisLineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset=3.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle=textstyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.majorGridLineStyle=clearlineStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy=CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic ;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
    axisSet.xAxis.labelExclusionRanges=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0)], nil];


    //Y Axis

    axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints=[CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
    axisSet.yAxis.labelFormatter = Yformatter;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = TickLineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = AxisLineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorGridLineStyle=gridLineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.labelTextStyle=ylabelstyle;

    //Labels
    CPTColor *targetlinecolor=[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:(float)186/255 green:(float)175/255 blue:(float)158/255 alpha:1];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *TargetLabelTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    TargetLabelTextStyle.color    = targetlinecolor;
    TargetLabelTextStyle.fontSize = 10.0f;
    TargetLabelTextStyle.fontName = @"OpenSans-Bold";
    TargetLabelTextStyle.textAlignment=CPTTextAlignmentRight;


    //Set graph specific properties

    if ([graphname isEqualToString:@"metabolism"]) {
        self.graphtitleLb.text=@"Metabolism (kCal/day)";
        MetabolismTest *latest=[metadata lastObject];
        NSTimeInterval mostrelevantdate = [[latest timestamp] timeIntervalSince1970];
        NSTimeInterval twoDaysAgo=mostrelevantdate-(2*oneDay);
        currentplotspace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(twoDaysAgo) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat((mostrelevantdate - twoDaysAgo)*2)];

        axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal=CPTDecimalFromFloat(metaYlow);
        axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal=CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");

        currentplotspace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(metaYlow)                                                            length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(metaYHigh-metaYlow)];

        axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:metaYinterval] decimalValue];


        axisSet.yAxis.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(metaYlow) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(metaYHigh-metaYlow)];
        self.Metabolismplot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc]
                           init ];
        self.Metabolismplot.identifier = @"metabolism";
        self.Metabolismplot.delegate=self;
        self.Metabolismplot.title=@"Metabolism";
        self.Metabolismplot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection=5;

        //Format plot and plot symbols

        CPTMutableLineStyle *plotLineStyle = [self.Metabolismplot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        plotLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0f;
        plotLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:(float)125/255 green:(float)177/255 blue:(float)52/255 alpha:1];
        self.Metabolismplot.dataLineStyle = plotLineStyle;
        self.Metabolismplot.dataSource = self;
        self.Metabolismplot.delegate=self;

        CPTMutableLineStyle *plotsymbolLinestyle=[CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        plotsymbolLinestyle.lineColor=[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0 green:0.6 blue:0 alpha:1];
        CPTPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
        greenCirclePlotSymbol.lineStyle=plotLineStyle;
        greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:(float)125/255 green:(float)177/255 blue:(float)52/255 alpha:1]];
        greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0);
        self.Metabolismplot.plotSymbol=greenCirclePlotSymbol;

        //Format plot and plot symbols for avg plots

        CPTMutableLineStyle *avgLineStyle = [self.metabolismHighplot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        avgLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.5f;
        avgLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
        CPTMutableLineStyle *clearsymbolLinestyle=[CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        clearsymbolLinestyle.lineColor=[CPTColor clearColor];
        CPTPlotSymbol *clearPlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol crossPlotSymbol];
        clearPlotSymbol.lineStyle=clearsymbolLinestyle;
        clearPlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
        clearPlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(0,0);

        //Average plots
        self.metabolismHighplot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init ];
        self.metabolismHighplot.identifier = @"metahigh";
        self.metabolismHighplot.delegate=self;
        self.metabolismHighplot.title=@"High";
        [self.metabolismHighplot setDataLineStyle:avgLineStyle];
        self.metabolismHighplot.dataSource = self;
        self.metabolismHighplot.delegate=self;
        self.metabolismHighplot.plotSymbol=clearPlotSymbol;

        self.metabolismLowplot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init ];
        self.metabolismLowplot.identifier = @"metalow";
        self.metabolismLowplot.delegate=self;
        self.metabolismLowplot.title=@"Low";
        [self.metabolismLowplot setDataLineStyle:avgLineStyle];
        self.metabolismLowplot.dataSource = self;
        self.metabolismLowplot.delegate=self;
        self.metabolismLowplot.plotSymbol=clearPlotSymbol;


        //Add background for the area between average plots
        [self.metabolismHighplot setAreaFill:[CPTFill fillWithColor:targetlinecolor]];
        self.metabolismHighplot.areaBaseValue=CPTDecimalFromInt(metaYlow);
        self.metabolismLowplot.areaFill=[CPTFill fillWithImage:[[CPTImage alloc] initForPNGFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"historyGraphBkgroungtemplate"] ofType:@"png"]]];
        self.metabolismLowplot.areaBaseValue=CPTDecimalFromInt(0);

        //Plot hierarchy
        [currentgraph addPlot:self.metabolismHighplot];
        [currentgraph addPlot:self.metabolismLowplot];
        [currentgraph addPlot:self.Metabolismplot];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code you have write?

Comment: @Braiam, Hi I am sharing the graph initialisation code: -(void)initgraphhost{
    CGRect graphcontainer=CGRectMake(0,0,568,300);
    self.graphhostview = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:graphcontainer];
    self.graphhostview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.graphhostview.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.graphhostview];
}

Comment: Please, edit your question and include the code.

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: @EricSkroch I am using 1.0 release

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues in the code you posted. You might try updating to a newer version of Core Plot. Version 1.3 is the current release.